# adding headlights to a car in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have an assignment that requires us to create a scene with a truck that is moving forward and backwards on a road. the truck consists of 2 rectangles for the body and 4 cylinders for the wheels. I created my truck with said objects and used the group function on the objects. my animation works perfectly, now we have to add head lights for the truck. I have created a spotlight(to use as a headlight) and added it to the scene but when I add it to the group so it moves with the truck, all I get is a blank canvas.

What methods can I use to add successfully add headlights to my truck?

Comment: Take a look at this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/lights-for-car-headlight/9410/4?u=prisoner849

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I needed